# What is the best way to parse this string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing

I have a string that I am reading from another system. It's basically a long string that represents a list of key value pairs that are separated by a space in between. It looks like this:

```
 key:value[space]key:value[space]key:value[space]
```

So I wrote this code to parse it:

```
string myString = ReadinString();
string[] tokens = myString.split(' ');
foreach (string token in tokens) {
     string key = token.split(':')[0];
     string value = token.split(':')[1];
     .  . . . 
}
```

The issue now is that some of the values have spaces in them so my "simplistic" split at the top no longer works. I wanted to see how I could still parse out the list of key value pairs (given space as a separator character) now that I know there also could be spaces in the value field as split doesn't seem like it's going to be able to work anymore.

**NOTE: I now confirmed that KEYs will NOT have spaces in them so I only have to worry about the values. Apologies for the confusion.**

Comment: do you have control over the input format?

Comment: @Jason - i am trying to get control, in which case i will change the separator character but i am still concerned that whatever character i use as a separator could also be in the value field.

Comment: Is it at least enforced that there is no `:` possible inside values? if not, you are stuck. If you generate the long string, then you have the possibility to escape the characters to avoid the trouble, but then you'll need something better than Split to read the input.

Comment: @jdehaan - good point.  I know there is definitely no ":" in the key but i can possibly imagine that showing up in the value one day (even though i can't find an example now). I obviously want to be a bit future proof

Comment: this cannot be done. How do you know if a word belongs to the value or to the next key?

Comment: Do you know in advance what allowable keys would be?  If so, and you have to allow for spaces and colons within your delimited strings, you can minimise your pain with a bit of substitution on the input.

Comment: +1 to vidstige, can we assume keys may not have spaces, can `:` be escaped?

Comment: @All - keys will NOT have spaces in them

Comment: @ ooo thanks for the clarification on the spaces not being in the keys. Now this problem is solvable (assuming there are no colons in both the key and the value).

Comment: It seems as though all the solutions below assume certain things about the value.  You will need to either get some control of the input, or at least some guarentee of the input, in order to insure proper parsing.  In other words, you must guarentee that the input follows some format (key, delimiter, value), where the delimiter can never be found in the key or value, or the value is always enclosed in quotes, or...  In other words, to use a pattern parser, there must be a guarenteed pattern to parse.

Comment: If values contain colons, this cannot be done. Consider `a:b c:d`. Is that two pairs, `a` => `b` and `c` => `d`, or just one, `a` => `b c:d`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
\w+:[\w\s]+(?![\w+:])
```

I tested it on

```
test:testvalue test2:test value test3:testvalue3
```

It returns three matches:

```
test:testvalue
test2:test value
test3:testvalue3
```

You can change `\w` to any character set that can occur in your input.

Code for testing this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+:[\w\s]+(?![\w+:])");
var test = "test:testvalue test2:test value test3:testvalue3";

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(test))
{
    var key = match.Value.Split(':')[0];
    var value = match.Value.Split(':')[1];

    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", key, value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

As Wonko the Sane pointed out, this regular expression will fail on values with `:`. If you predict such situation, use `\w+:[\w: ]+?(?![\w+:])` as the regular expression. This will still fail when a colon in `value` is preceded by space though... I'll think about solution to this.

Comment: "any sufficiently advanced regex is indistinguishable from magic" ;)

Comment: Note: `\s` will also match tab and newline, so if you think they can occur in values change `[\w\s]` to `[\w ]`

Comment: Note - "test:testvalue test2:test:withcolon value test3:testvalue3" fails test2.

Comment: @Wonko the Sane: you're right. I added solution to this. Still not perfect though.

Comment: Right - the problem is that to use a parser on a pattern, the pattern must *always* be predictable.

Comment: ...and now you have two problems. :)

Answer (score 5):

This cannot work without changing your split from a space to something else such as a "|".

Consider this:

Alfred Bester:**Alfred Bester Alfred**:Alfred Bester

- Is this Key "Alfred Bester" & value Alfred" or Key "Alfred" & value "Bester Alfred"?

Answer (score 4):

```
string input = "foo:Foobarius Maximus Tiberius Kirk bar:Barforama zap:Zip Brannigan";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+):([^:]+)(?![\w+:])"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", 
       match.Groups[1].Value, 
       match.Groups[2].Value
      );
}
```

Gives you:

```
foo = Foobarius Maximus Tiberius Kirk
bar = Barforama
zap = Zip Brannigan
```

Comment: Nice! I like this solution better because it groups the key and value rather than relying on a split. This puts more logic in the regex and allows for more customization, such as the potential for using Google-style groupings to encapsulate value strings.
e.g. key1:(this:is:a funky value)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to Url encode the content between the space (**The keys and the values not the : symbol**) but this would require that you have control over the Input Method.

Or you could simply use another format (Like XML or JSON), but again you will need control over the Input Format.

If you can't control the input format you could always use a Regular expression and that searches for single spaces where a word plus : follows.

**Update (Thanks Jon Grant)**
It appears that you can have spaces in the key and the value. If this is the case you will need to seriously rethink your strategy as even Regex won't help.

Comment: As much as I hate Regex, I think it is the way to go in this instance.

Comment: That's why I use it. Not that I can but because I have too. :D

Comment: The question says there can be spaces in the key AND the value... even regexes can't solve that problem.

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit of the original question.  That being the case, you're right and the OP  is likely to have to resort to best guesses...  Maybe if the keys are from a predefined list of possibilities?

Comment: Well it's possible. You could probably then just scan the string and search for the location of the {key}: and then substring it from that location to the next : and then check for any key that is still in the string and replace it. But this seems very "Ugly". Can't you change the Input Format ? Or is it a third party lib?

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "key1:value key2:value key3:value";
Dictionary<string, string> dic = input.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Split(':')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

The first will produce an array:

```
"key:value", "key:value"
```

Then an array of arrays:

```
{ "key", "value" }, { "key", "value" }
```

And then a dictionary:

```
"key" => "value", "key" => "value"
```

Note, that `Dictionary<K,V>` doesn't allow duplicated keys, it will raise an exception in such a case. If such a scenario is possible, use `ToLookup()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression can solve your problem:

```
private void DoSplit(string str)
{
    str += str.Trim() + " ";
    string patterns = @"\w+:([\w+\s*])+[^!\w+:]";
    var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(patterns);
    var ms = r.Matches(str);
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match item in ms)
    {
        string[] s = item.Value.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could take your method and expand upon it slightly to deal with this stuff...

Kind of pseudocode:

```
List<string> parsedTokens = new List<String>();
string[] tokens = myString.split(' ');
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    // We need to deal with the special case of the last item, 
    // or if the following item does not contain a colon.
    if(i == tokens.Length - 1 || tokens[i+1].IndexOf(':' > -1)
    {
        parsedTokens.Add(tokens[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        // This bit needs to be refined to deal with values with multiple spaces...
        parsedTokens.Add(tokens[i] + " " + tokens[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to split on the colon...  That way, your first array item would be the name of the first key, second item would be the value of the first key and then name of the second key (can use LastIndexOf to split it out), and so on. This would obviously get very messy if the values can include colons, or the keys can contain spaces, but in that case you'd be pretty much out of luck...

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it (given the rules below).  It parses the keys and values and returns them in a `Dictonary<string, string>` data structure.  I have added some code at the end that assumes given your example that the last value of the entire string/stream will be appended with a [space]:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParseKeyValues(string input)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string[] parts = input.Split(':');

            string key = parts[0];
            string value;

            int currentIndex = 1;

            while (currentIndex < parts.Length-1)
            {
                int indexOfLastSpace=parts[currentIndex].LastIndexOf(' ');
                value = parts[currentIndex].Substring(0, indexOfLastSpace);
                items.Add(key, value);
                key = parts[currentIndex].Substring(indexOfLastSpace + 1);
                currentIndex++;
            }
            value = parts[parts.Length - 1].Substring(0,parts[parts.Length - 1].Length-1);


            items.Add(key, parts[parts.Length-1]);

            return items;

        }
```

Note: this algorithm assumes the following rules:

1. No spaces in the values
2. No colons in the keys
3. No colons in the values

Answer (score 0):

Without any Regex nor string concat, and as an enumerable (it supposes keys don't have spaces, but values can):

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Split(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            yield break;

        int keyStart = 0;
        int keyEnd = -1;
        int lastSpace = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == ' ')
            {
                lastSpace = i;
                continue;
            }

            if (text[i] == ':')
            {
                if (lastSpace >= 0)
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(text.Substring(keyStart, keyEnd - keyStart), text.Substring(keyEnd + 1, lastSpace - keyEnd - 1));
                    keyStart = lastSpace + 1;
                }
                keyEnd = i;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (keyEnd >= 0)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(text.Substring(keyStart, keyEnd - keyStart), text.Substring(keyEnd + 1));
    }
```